# Problem with a cheater

Tags: cheating, qualifying-exam

I will be taking something similar to an entry exam for university. I also had another exam last week and then one person tried to cheat off me, but I didn't let him. Now I'm a little bit anxious that in the next exam he could sit somewhere close to me again. This exam will also have a listening part so I would like to take a place somewhere in the first rows so that I could hear and write down more effectively. Actually it's not likely that this guy will be anywhere near me - there will be many people at this exam, we may not even be in the same examination hall. But I still have worries so that's why I'm posting this question. I will surely do my best to sit as far from him as possible, but if by some really bad chance we are near each other again (for example few free places in the first rows etc.), I'm planning to stay in the first rows just for the listening and after it's over, to ask some of the invigilators to move elsewhere. Do you think there is a chance of me getting into trouble for doing this? Should I also explain them the reason and what would be the best thing to say (I prefer not to get into details at all)? What are your thoughts on this? I have enough stress with the exam, so having to think how to deal with some lazy a**hole is the last thing I need right now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrive early and choose a good seat. Focus on the exam and take a bit of care that your work isn't easily visible. Beyond that, relax as much as you can, especially about the circumstances.

I wouldn't raise any issue with a proctor unless you actually need to, but then, don't hesitate to ask to be reseated. You don't need to offer an explanation unless asked. But you shouldn't have any negative consequences if you need to act.

Don't do anything that might be interpreted as disruptive such as shouting at someone copying.